# pypyodbc python module to connect postgresql on windows and linux

Tags: python, windows, postgresql

Unable to connect to `postgreSQL` using `python pypyodbc` module and getting error:

> [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Data Source name not found and no default driver specified.

Connection string used:

```
    dbconn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)};'+ 'Server=127.0.0.1' 
             + ';Port=5432;' + ';database=#####;'+ 'uid=######;' + ';pwd=######;' )
```

I have been searching on net over and over again but didn't found any thing,
Do I need to install supporting driver, if so please specify the way to do so.

Comment: Can't you use Psycopg?

Comment: i was already using the script on SQL server using pypyodbc, now intended to use the same script with slight changes, but again changing the module for almost 151 script is bit tricky